# RN "TypeError: Network request failed" - production - random

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I know some questions about the subject has been opened here and there, but my issue is different :

- all the other ones appear in **dev mode**, in my case it's in **production**,
- a very big percentage of requests pass, a few of them is `TypeError: Network request failed` - but sometimes for critical requests
- it's random, not always the same request. Sometimes it passes, sometimes not.
- it appears to three on my projects, one is on AWS the other one on Clever-Cloud, both are projects between 1000 and 5000 users, servers are quite too big for what they do - I think I removed the risk of a server fault. Even if... I can reproduce locally when I don't start the api locally. So it's like the api is not responding, but as I said, I don't think so.

I have no clue where to dig anymore...

I can give you my `API.js` service file, maybe you'll find what's wrong ?

```js
import URI from 'urijs';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

import { getUserToken, wipeData } from '../utils/data';

import { SCHEME, MW_API_HOST } from '../config';
import deviceInfoModule from 'react-native-device-info';
import { capture } from '../utils/sentry';


const unauthorisedHandler = (navigation) => {
  wipeData();
  navigation.reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: 'Auth' }] });
};

const checkNetwork = async (test = false) => {
  const isConnected = await NetInfo.fetch().then((state) => state.isConnected);
  if (!isConnected || test) {
    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 1500));
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

class ApiService {
  host = MW_API_HOST;
  scheme = SCHEME;
  getUrl = (path, query) => {
    return new URI().host(this.host).scheme(this.scheme).path(path).setSearch(query).toString();
  };
  execute = async ({ method = 'GET', path = '', query = {}, headers = {}, body = null }) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        method,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
          appversion: deviceInfoModule.getBuildNumber(),
          appdevice: Platform.OS,
          currentroute: this.navigation?.getCurrentRoute?.()?.name,
          ...headers,
        },
        body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : null,
      };

      const url = this.getUrl(path, query);
      console.log('url: ', url);
      const canFetch = await checkNetwork();
      if (!canFetch) return;
      let response;

      // To try to avoid mysterious `TypeError: Network request failed` error
      // that throws an error directly
      // we try catch and try one more time.
      
      try {
        response = await fetch(url, config);
      } catch (e) {
        if (e?.toString().includes('Network request failed')) {
          // try again
          await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 250));
          console.log('try again because Network request failed');
          response = await fetch(url, config);
        } else {
          throw e;
        }
      }

      if (!response.ok) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
          const token = await getUserToken();
          if (token) unauthorisedHandler(API.navigation);
          return response;
        }
      }
      if (response.json) return await response.json();

      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      capture(e, { extra: { method, path, query, headers, body } });
      return { ok: false, error: "Sorry, an error occured, technical team has been warned." };
    }
  };

  executeWithToken = async ({ method = 'GET', path = '', query = {}, headers = {}, body = null }) => {
    const token = await getUserToken();
    if (token) headers.Authorization = token;
    return this.execute({ method, path, query, headers, body });
  };

  get = async (args) => this.executeWithToken({ method: 'GET', ...args });
  post = async (args) => this.executeWithToken({ method: 'POST', ...args });
  put = async (args) => this.executeWithToken({ method: 'PUT', ...args });
  delete = async (args) => this.executeWithToken({ method: 'DELETE', ...args });
}

const API = new ApiService();
export default API;
```

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I just added my answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/73120564/5225096

Answer (score 1):

Talking with experts here and there, it seems that it's normal : internet network is not 100% reliable, so sometimes, request fail, for a reason that we can't anticipate (tunnel, whatever).

I ended up using `fetch-retry` and I still have a few of those, but much less !